# List Database Scoped DM Views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Server-scoped Dynamic Management View are stored only in the Master database.

```
SELECT name, type, type_desc
FROM sys.system_objects
WHERE name LIKE 'dm%'
ORDER BY name
```

How to list Database-Scoped DM Views and where it stored?

Can you advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Server-scoped Dynamic Management View are stored only in the Master
>   database.

Not exactly. DMVs are stored in the internal mssqlsystemresource database but are visible in all databases. You should get the same results if you run your query from any database, assuming you're not limited by permissions.

Database-scoped DMVs generally have prefix 'dm_db_' and can be listed with the query below.

```
SELECT name, type, type_desc
FROM sys.system_objects
WHERE name LIKE N'dm%[_]db[_]%'
ORDER BY name;
```

Comment: HI Dan, Thanks for your reply.

 If Granting "VIEW SERVER STATE" privilege to a user is enough to view both dm% and dm_db_% ( Server and DB Scoped ] views?

Then what additional privileges a user will get by granting "VIEW DATABASE STATE"

Comment: Granting `VIEW SERVER STATE` implies `VIEW DATABASE STATE` too. If you did need to grant `VIEW SERVER STATE` only, an explicit `DENY VIEW DATABASE STATE` would be needed.